# How to check django ModelForm field type in html?

Tags: django

I need to do some logic in HTML page depending on field type. 
For example something to do if input is type="text" or if it is textarea or checkbox....

```
{% for field in formFields %}
    {{field}}
{% endfor %}
```

When i do something like this: `{{field.field}}` i get something like this:

```
&lt;django.forms.fields.IntegerField object at 0x04812750&gt;
```

How to use this or is better way?

Answer (score 3):

Specify field type in your views(or `forms.py`), do not contain complex logic in your template for field rendering,

```
class FormClass(ModelForm):
    my_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Then my_field will be rendered as textarea in template, each field type has its own widget, read the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/).

Comment: You did not understand.. I have texarea, checkbox etc.. But i want django class names.. I managed to solve by writing custom template tag...

Comment: @milandjukic88 you mean django class names for field type?

Comment: Writing a tag or filter is the best solution (as you do) in that situation.